# Android, run some lines of code at specified time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText input=(EditText)parent.findViewById(R.id.input);

        //run at specified time
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //run at specified time

    }
});
```

I know there are two ways to do that

First is handler, but it does not work when device sleep

Second is AlarmManager, but it must create another activity or service

I just want to run a piece of code and these codes have many dependency to the current activity, is there any other way to run the code at specified time?

Comment: just set the phone not to sleep at current activity

Comment: @CL So what is your goal?

Comment: Any problem by using AlarmManager with broadcastreceiver?

Comment: Are you trying to show a Toast at a specific time? Or are you intending to do some long running operations at a specific time?

Answer (score 2):

For run some lines of code at specified time you need to user Timer class of android.Use Timer class not Countdown Timer class.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //your lines of code at specified time

        }
    }, delays Millisecond, Interval Millisecond);
```

- delay in millisecond means Timer start after this millisecond
- interval millisecond means Timer run at this specific time every time.